# In a Windows batch file, how to FOR /F with a command having multiple quoted strings

Tags: windows, batch-file

The following command works fine:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\KeePass Password Safe 2\KPScript.exe" -c:GetEntryString "C:\Users\Me\Documents\KeePass Database.kdbx" -useraccount -field:Password -ref-Title:"Data Partition" -FailIfNotExists -FailIfNoEntry
```

It returns a password out of a KeePass database. In a batch file, I want to put the result of that into a variable, so I can pass it to another program.

I tried the following in a batch file:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
FOR /F "tokens=* usebackq" %%F IN (`"C:\Program Files (x86)\KeePass Password Safe 2\KPScript.exe" -c:GetEntryString "C:\Users\Me\Documents\KeePass Database.kdbx" -useraccount -field:Password -ref-Title:"Data Partition" -FailIfNotExists -FailIfNoEntry`) DO SET pw=%%F
ECHO %pw%
ENDLOCAL
```

But calling this batch file returns:

'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

I tried putting quotes around the command in FOR:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
FOR /F "tokens=* usebackq" %%F IN (`""C:\Program Files (x86)\KeePass Password Safe 2\KPScript.exe" -c:GetEntryString "C:\Users\Me\Documents\KeePass Database.kdbx" -useraccount -field:Password -ref-Title:"Data Partition" -FailIfNotExists -FailIfNoEntry"`) DO SET pw=%%F
ECHO %pw%
ENDLOCAL
```

And this time I got:

\KeePass was unexpected at this time.

What is the correct syntax to make this work?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apply the latter approach *and* escape the closing parenthesis using a caret as follows:

```
FOR /F "tokens=* usebackq" %%F IN (`""C:\Program Files (x86^)\KeePass …
```

or

```
FOR /F "tokens=* usebackq" %%F IN (`""%ProgramFiles(x86):)=^)%\KeePass …
```

Moreover, always

- set variables with *Delayed Expansion* disabled to prevent expansion of (possibly present) `!` exclamation marks;
- [set variables using double quotes](https://ss64.com/nt/set.html) (as `SET "pw=%%F"` below) to escape (possibly present) `cmd`-poisonous characters like `&`, `<`, `|` etc…;
- use variables with *Delayed Expansion* enabled.

Then, your script could look as follows (**updated**):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
rem remove variable `pw`
set "pw="
FOR /F "tokens=* usebackq" %%F IN (`""C:\Program Files (x86^)\KeePass Password Safe 2\KPScript.exe" -c:GetEntryString "C:\Users\Me\Documents\KeePass Database.kdbx" -useraccount -field:Password -ref-Title:"Data Partition" -FailIfNotExists -FailIfNoEntry"`) DO (
   rem set only first output line to variable `pw`
   if NOT defined pw SET "pw=%%F"
)
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
ECHO !pw!
ENDLOCAL
```

Comment: JosefZ: This is awesome.  Thank you so much.  New problem: When I run just that first command I gave above, it returns 2 lines, the password and "OK: Operation completed successfully."  Unfortunately, %pw% is getting set to the latter.

Comment: @uncaged Answer updated. Sorry, I couldn't  test the code not having `KPScript.exe` installed.

Comment: Wow, I'm so impressed.  If you're on Fiverr or UpWork, please let me know.  I'd happily pay you for occasional help.

Comment:  If my answer was helpful, please consider marking it as accepted. [See this page](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/) for an explanation of why this is important.